# Auto upload public key to Gitlab

Tags: ssh, gitlab

Is there any to way to automatically upload the public key to **Gitlab** after generating the *private/public key* pair.
I want to automate these steps:

Open *Gitlab* and enter **Settings-> SSH Keys**. Then paste the public key and click the Add Key button to add.

Comment: You could use something like phantomjs.  I know phantomjs is not longer supported but maybe you can find something like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *GitLab* REST API endpoint which could be use to automate that step.

See [User -- Add SSH key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#add-ssh-key)

```
POST /user/keys
```

with as a data:

```yaml
{
  "title": "ABC",
  "key": "ssh-dss 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 loic@call",
  "expires_at": "2016-01-21T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```